# ¿Que puede estar mal ?(Programación de estructuras de control)

Tags: java

La forma más fácil es con do-while sin embargo quise intentarlo de otra forma aunque fuera más difícil. (Es un simple juego que pide al usuario que adivine los números). 
Nota: Probablemente tenga que estudiar estructuras de control para entender el flujo del programa ya que en su momento quería llegar rápido a POO.
Código: (Perdón por mi forma desorganizada de escribir código)¿Puede que las sentencias anidadas tengan algo que ver?

```
package Main.java;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int aleatorio =(int)(Math.random()*100);/*Ya usé int aleatorio = (1*100) para comprobar y solo funciona el
    primer has ganado*/

        System.out.println("Digite un numero del 1 al 100");
        int D = scanner.nextInt();

        if(aleatorio==D) {

            System.out.println("Has Ganado");
        }   

        while(aleatorio<D) {

            System.out.println("Más alto:");
            int c = scanner.nextInt();//Falta llenar esta parte 

            if(aleatorio==c) {

                System.out.println("Has Ganado");
            }

            while(aleatorio>D) {

                System.out.println("Más Bajo:");
                int B = scanner.nextInt();

                if(aleatorio==B) {

                    System.out.println("Has Ganado");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente es un desastre, pero dos cosas (o tres). Primero donde dices "Más alto" debe ser "Más bajo" y viceversa. Luego si utilizas otras variables - **c** y **B** (no vamos a discutir los nombres) esto no va a funcionar nunca. Debes usar **D**. Algo así:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);/*
                 * Ya usé int aleatorio = (1*100) para comprobar y solo funciona el primer has ganado
                 */

System.out.println(aleatorio);
System.out.println("Digite un numero del 1 al 100");
int D = scanner.nextInt();
if (aleatorio == D) {

    System.out.println("Has Ganado");

}

while (aleatorio < D) {

    System.out.println("Más bajo:");
    D = scanner.nextInt();// Falta llenar esta parte

    if (aleatorio == D) {

        System.out.println("Has Ganado");

    }

    while (aleatorio > D) {

        System.out.println("Más alto:");
        D = scanner.nextInt();

        if (aleatorio == D) {

            System.out.println("Has Ganado");

        }

    }

}

scanner.close();
```

Y por último - cierra el objeto scanner. Además te lo pide al compilar ;-)

Saludos.

Firmado:
Sick Boy

Answer (score 1):

En adición a la respuesta de @evgeni-enchev , es recomendable reducir bucles y dejarlo en solo uno.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);/*
             * Ya usé int aleatorio = (1*100) para comprobar y solo funciona el primer has ganado
             */

System.out.println(aleatorio);
System.out.println("Digite un numero del 1 al 100");
int D = scanner.nextInt();
if (aleatorio == D) {    
    System.out.println("Has Ganado");    
}
//Hasta aquí todo se mantiene igual
while (aleatorio != D) { //Nos quedamos dentro del bucle hasta que aleatorio == D
    if(D>aleatorio)
    {
        System.out.println("Más bajo:");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Más alto:");
    }
    D = scanner.nextInt();    
}
//Si salimos del bucle, quiere decir que aleatorio == D
scanner.close();
System.out.println("Has Ganado");
```

Como recomendación ( y como te han comentado), el nombre de las variables. Usa nombres que se pueda deducir que valor es. Mas que nada por que si miras tu código dentro de varios meses, te sera mas fácil comprender el funcionamiento.